# The page or ad listing you are trying to reach no longer exists or has expired

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, rewrite-rules

I have this URL here `https://www.gundogworld.co.uk/judge/`. I am wishing for this to be a simple archive page. On this page, it has the body class `class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-tribe_ext_judge logged-in tribe-js` I cannot get the `/judge` to display the archives no matter what I try. `mod_rewrite` is active on the server, I turned all caching off, visited permalink and re-save after every attempt. in my child theme i have `archive-judge.php`, `single-judge.php` and `taxonomy-judge.php`.

This is the code I have in the plugin where the post is registered,
I have turned all plugins off (except the 2 required) and reverted to 2016 I have tried everything I can reading google for 3 weeks with no win!

```
 /**
     * Set the arguments for and register the post type.
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
     *
     * @see Linked_Posts::register_linked_post_type()
     */
    public function register_our_post_type() {
        $post_type_key = self::POST_TYPE_KEY;

        $labels = array(
            'name'                    => esc_html_x( 'Judges', 'Post type general name', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'singular_name'           => esc_html_x( 'Judge', 'Post type singular name', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'singular_name_lowercase' => esc_html_x( 'judge', 'Post type singular name', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            // not part of WP's labels but is required by Linked_Posts::register_linked_post_type()
            'add_new'                 => esc_html_x( 'Add New', $post_type_key, 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'add_new_item'            => esc_html__( 'Add New Judge', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'edit_item'               => esc_html__( 'Edit Judge', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'new_item'                => esc_html__( 'New Judge', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'view_item'               => esc_html__( 'View Judge', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'view_items'              => esc_html__( 'View Judges', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'search_items'            => esc_html__( 'Search Judges', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'not_found'               => esc_html__( 'No judges found', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'      => esc_html__( 'No judges found in Trash', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'all_items'               => esc_html__( 'Judges', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'archives'                => esc_html__( 'Judge Archives', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'insert_into_item'        => esc_html__( 'Insert into judge', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item'   => esc_html__( 'Uploaded to this judge', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'items_list'              => esc_html__( 'Judges list', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'items_list_navigation'   => esc_html__( 'Judges list navigation', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'description'         => esc_html__( 'Judges linked to Events', 'tribe-ext-judge-linked-post-type' ),
            'public'              => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => 'edit.php?post_type=' . Tribe__Events__Main::POSTTYPE,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-businessman',
            'capability_type'     => $post_type_key,
            'map_meta_cap'        => true, // must be true for $this->set_our_capabilities() to take effect
            'supports'            => array(
                'author',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'revisions',
                'thumbnail',
                'title',
            ),
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'rewrite'             => array(
                'slug'       => 'judge',
                'with_front' => false,
            ),
        );

        register_post_type( $post_type_key, $args );
    }
```

the rewrite rules are as follows

```
judge/?$    index.php?post_type=tribe_ext_judge other
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$    index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] page
([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$    index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] post
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works just fine. The thing that I think you are missing is *flushing the permalinks* by going to *WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks* and click `Save Changes`.

Comment: thank you Vlad, i wish i had £1 for every time i had , flushing the permalinks by going to WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and click Save Changes.!! it must be in the hundreds!!!  how would i debug from here? it must be a clash in /judge name in database or a server problem if code works fine for you! doing both is a little out of my comfort zone!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't help you. Now I see your CPT has the slug `tribe_ext_judge` while you say you have `archive-judge.php`. You should have `archive-tribe_ext_judge.php`. Maybe this will help. I would also use this rewrite analysis helper plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to see what `https://www.gundogworld.co.uk/judge/` get rewritten to.

Comment: thanks vlad , 'has_archive'        => true,
            'rewrite'             => array(
                'slug'       => 'judge',
                'with_front' => false,
            ), is the slug not renamed to 'judge' ?

Comment: That slug is related to the URL slug, not the post type ID or name if you like.  It is quite wrong to speak of post type name as slug but it has become somewhat of a habit in the WordPress world, and I am guilty also. So the two are different.

Comment: it results in same outcome (archive-tribe_ext_judge.php) , ill have a look at the info you gave above wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector

Comment: the rewrite rules from  rewrite-rules- inspector are as follows judge/?$ index.php?post_type=tribe_ext_judge other
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] page
([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] post

Comment: The rewrite rules seem to be fine.

Comment: If the custom post type rewrite rules seem correct , the code seems correct , what else is there that could be causing this , can you point me in a direction please?I turned of the rewrite rules for the URL slug but still had the same outcome.

Comment: I sort of out of ideas. Do you possibly have a page or a post with the exact same slug (`judge`)?

Comment: I may of created something a while ago (years) before I took the site down this root , looking in wp-admin at posts and pages there is nothing.i wouldn't  know where else or how to loo /